# What mantras are given in Vinayaka samhita of sama Veda?

Tags: vedas, ganesha, sama-veda

According to this [page](https://animeshnagarblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/samaveda-rudram/), vinayaka samhita of sama Veda glorifies Ganesha. what 4 hymns are present in the following samhita?